# jQuery toggle text defined only in html

Tags: jquery, toggle, custom-data-attribute

This has been answered some times but mine is a different approach.

I want to toggle (via jQuery) a text on click. But I want to have this text defined in the html (because it is multilanguage and it depends in langs, more preciselly in Smarty variables) so the `$(this).html(condition ? "Some" : "Other" )` doesn't work.

My actual approach is:

**HTML**

```
<a class="readmore" href="#content">
    <span class="text" rel="Menos">Más</span>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".readmore").click(function(event) {
    var contentSelectAnt = $(this).find(".text").html();
    var contentSelect = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).find(".text").html(contentSelect);
    $(this).attr("rel",contentSelectAnt);
)};
```

But I don't quite like the redundancy of the code and the unapropiate use of the `rel` attribute. I am sure there is a more *jquery* style solution.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach data via the data method. However, you still have the problem of the initial and opposing state.

```
<a href="#content" data-content="SomeOtherContent">Text</a>

$('a').click(function()
{
     var currentObj = $(this);
     var currentText = currentObj.html();
     currentObj.html(currentObj.data('content'));
     currentObj.data('content', currentText);
});
```

Comment: I am testing this now. Will the data attributes give problems in older browsers?

Comment: data is jquery so it should be cross browser OK.

Comment: Works great! A Frédérik Hidis posted the same answer but more specific to the code in the question, but he deleted it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Edited answer to apply to the question's code, hope this passes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually struggling to understand what you are trying to do, but cobbled together a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aTLRU/1/)***

Don't know if thats what you mean but that was my understanding of the question.

EDIT:

***[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/aTLRU/3/)*** with the proper functionality?

***[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/aTLRU/4/)*** without the use of anchor tags.

Comment: upvote for the jsFiddle (although it is not what I am looking for, thankyou)

Comment: Ah...I understand what you mean now. But I would go along the same lines as Brian Fisher below. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aTLRU/3/ for multilanguage support.

Comment: You could even go without the anchor tags if you wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/aTLRU/4/

Answer (score 0):

How about just using two spans:

```
<a class="readmore" href="#content">
    <span class="text">Más</span>
    <span class="text" style="display: none;">Menos</span>
</a>
```

With javascript:

```
$(".readmore").click(function(event) {
    $(this).find('.text').toggle();
    return false;    
 });
```

Here is a demo, http://jsfiddle.net/Fq4bT/

Comment: I would write it $(".readmore").click(function(event) { $('.text').toggle(); return false; });  OR $(".readmore").click(function(event) {     $('#more, #less').toggle();     return false;      });

Comment: to make is "safer" you could select the children of the clicked as well. (so if there are more '.readmore', it works on just this one instance.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I just wanted to have a working sample at first.  But when I went to simplify the code as you suggested in your first comment I also added the find on the the clicked element to limit the search to the descendants.

Comment: This one's good but I don't like to have the two spans, one with the inline style. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to use an inline style you can use an external stylesheet by adding a class to the hidden span or without adding anything and using a.readmore span:last-child {display: none;}